# Cannot resolve getSystemService method in ListView adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working through John Horton's *Android Programming for Beginners*, and am currently attempting to create a note-taking app. Horton has just introduced `ListViews`. However, I am having trouble with the `adapter` `class`:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Note> mNoteList = new ArrayList<Note>(); 

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mNoteList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Note getItem(int whichItem){
        return mNoteList.get(whichItem);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int whichItem){
        return whichItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){

        // check if view has been inflated already
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // ERROR HERE

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, viewGroup, false);

        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

The problem is in the `getView` method, where I'm attempting to `inflate` the `layout`: `Android Studio throws an error: 'Cannot resolve getSystemService(java.lang.String)'.`

As a complete newcomer just following through the book I have no idea where to go from here or what to try to resolve it - can anyone help?

Comment: That basically means it cannot find the getSystemService in the current class (NoteAdapter) or in the super class (BaseAdapter). Have you imported BaseAdapter at the top of the file? Can you see the source of BaseAdapter?

Comment: Guys, I'm an idiot. I put the class in a separate file but it should be in _MainActivity_. (－‸ლ). Works fine when you put it there. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to get a `LayoutInflater` is by calling `getLayoutInflater()` on an `Activity`. That way, the activity's theme is taken into account. If `NoteAdapter` is defined inside of an `Activity`, just call `getLayoutInflater()`. If `NoteAdapter` is defined in its own separate Java class file, pass in a `LayoutInflater` via the constructor.

To more directly address your question, any `View`, like `ListView`, can call `getContext()` to get a `Context`. That is where `getSystemService()` is defined. So, replacing `getSystemService()` with `viewGroup.getContext().getSystemService()` would work.

Comment: Thanks for the post but my condition was to getSystemServices in fragment, though your post gave me a hint to work around like this in my fragment
  this.getActivity().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass **Context** to your adapter and then replace this line:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
 `view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem, viewGroup,false);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class variable and a Constructor for your adapter:

```
Context context;
public NoteAdapter(Context context){
this.context = context;
}
```

Then initialize the layoutinflater the following way:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my views, if you are learning then learn RecyclerView. bcz it is better than ListView. i am not saying that ListView has been depricated. But there alot of internal things in which RecyclerView is better.

Following is example of Adapter

```
public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Note> mNoteList = new ArrayList<Note>();

    Context context;

    public NoteAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return mNoteList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Note getItem(int whichItem){
        return mNoteList.get(whichItem);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int whichItem){
        return whichItem;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){

        // check if view has been inflated already 
        if (view == null){

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, viewGroup, false);

        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Inside MainActivity.java

```
NoteAdapter noteA = new NoteAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

OR

```
NoteAdapter noteA = new NoteAdapter(getContext());
```

OR

`NoteAdapter noteA = new NoteAdapter(getActivity);`

//  if in Fragment

OR

`NoteAdapter noteA = new NoteAdapter(getApplicationContext);`

// will work but no need to use it. bcz this is context of whole application. For an adapter you don't need context of whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext = null;

    public NoteAdapter(Context context){
       mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){

        // check if view has been inflated already
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // ERROR HERE

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, viewGroup, false);

        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the constructor of Adapter: like follow :

```
Context context;
public NoteAdapter(Context context)
{
  this.context = context
}
```

Now use this context:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

mContext is Context which you pass to Custom Adapter

```
  public boolean CheckInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            //we are connected to a network
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }//end of check internet
```